# Why I am not able to connect to ftp server via unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

```
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd folder_name
get *.zip
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

I get the same error message as `Not Connected/Connection refused` for both the codes but manually it works from the command line.

```
DoFtp=NewDoFtp.FTP

echo "open ftp.xyx.com" > $DoFtp
echo "user username password" >> $DoFtp
echo "bye" >> $DoFtp

ftp -vn < "$DoFtp"
```

Comment: In which way your issue related to Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: This unix environment is actually a GCP instance. Note: The firewall ports are already opened for my ftp server.

Comment: Thanks! On the other hand, you wrote that "manually it works from the command line." so it looks like the problem only with your scripts and not related to GCP.

Comment: You should **not** use FTP, ever.  This protocol is not encrypted and dangerous.  You should use SSH.  `sftp` and `scp`, part of SSH, can be used to copy files, in a secure and easily "scriptable" matter.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you provide an alternative sftp code for my second code block ?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the second code block and it worked.
Maybe you have bash special chars in password (like $)?